# Replace new line with space regex

Tags: regex, eclipse

Hi i want to join first line with next paragraph. So basically remove \n from 1. and join it with second paragraph.

```
1. 
This is the second line: 
A) xyz89797 
B) xyz89797 

2. 
This is the another line: 
A) xyz89797 
B) xyz89797
```

I want to make above paragraph as

```
1. This is the second line: 
A) xyz89797 
B) xyz89797 

2. This is the another line: 
A) xyz89797 
B) xyz89797
```

In eclipse replace i am use [0-9]\. which is matching decimal uptill . but cant get the new line \n\r and what should i replace it with?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Find:

```
(\d+)\.\n
```

Replace:

```
$1.
```

I used the character class `\d`, and allowed for multiple digits with `+`.

The `$1` is the first capture group (everything inside parentheses).